# MaterialUI component is not working for react component

Tags: reactjs, mui

I am trying to use MUI readymade components in my react application,
I import everything correctly, after all these when I am running the app, there is the only element shows in the browser, not its style.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '../node_modules/muicss/lib/react/button';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">button</Button>
          <Button size="small" color="primary" variant="flat">button</Button>
          <Button size="small" color="primary" variant="raised">button</Button>
          <Button size="small" color="primary" variant="fab">+</Button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button color="primary">button</Button>
          <Button color="primary" variant="flat">button</Button>
          <Button color="primary" variant="raised">button</Button>
          <Button color="primary" variant="fab">+</Button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button size="large" color="primary">button</Button>
          <Button size="large" color="primary" variant="flat">button</Button>
          <Button size="large" color="primary" variant="raised">button</Button>
          <Button size="large" color="primary" variant="fab">+</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey Welcome to SO. Can you please share the code so that we can help you with fixing the styles.

Comment: I add the code please have a look on it

Comment: Try importing button like this import Button from 'muicss/lib/react/button'; May the path is incorrect and react treating it as normal button

Comment: Try button import like this "import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";" without double quotes

Comment: @Nisfan It's not material-ui library it's muicss

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set the exact path for node_modules just type the component name for importing any component.
Like below import statement in material ui doc.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

Comment: It's not material-ui library it's muicss

Comment: its also mentioned there use button like this: import Button from 'muicss/lib/react/button';